# MatLab - como colocar um expoente no xlabel

Tags: matlab

Boa tarde. Quero colocar no xlabel as unidades de m^(-1).

```
f=[40.82,52.63,75.80];
inversoL=[1/0.730,1/0.600,1/0.400];
coeficientes=polyfit(inversoL,f,1)
f_est=coeficientes(1).*inversoL+coeficientes(2);
plot(inversoL,f,'kd-');
hold on;
plot(inversoL,f_est, 'ro-');
title('Frequência em função do inverso do comprimento da corda','FontSize', 16); 
xlabel('Inverso do comprimento da corda m^(-1)','FontSize', 16,'Color','k');
```

O problema é que só o parêntesis curvo é que fica em expoente, e eu queria utilizar as unidades do inverso do metro ou m^(-1). Obrigada a quem puder ajudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Já encontrei a solução. Fica o código igual, apenas se altera esta linha:

```
xlabel('Inverso do comprimento da corda m^{-1}','FontSize', 16,'Color','k');
```